# Unsubscribing on destroy for concatenated observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

Greetings fellow programmers,

I have a subscription to an observable in an Angular-component where I want to immediately run the subscribe function on the first emission, but debounce all the subsequent, implemented like this:

```
concat(
  inputStream$.pipe(take(1)),
  inputStream$.pipe(
    skip(1),
    debounceTime(500))
).subscribe(val => someFunction(val));
```

However, as `inputStream$` comes from an external service, I wish to end the subscription on the destruction of the component. As is usual, I have a local `destroy$` that emits on `ngOnDestroy` and was about to do the usual `takeUntil(this.destroy$)`.

However in this case I'm a bit concerned about where I should end the subscription. Would it be within the concat inside both the individual pipes, or inside a pipe on the concat-stream itself? Or is there even another better way to do this correctly for concatting streams?

In other words, my two suggestions are:

**Inside each pipe:**

```
concat(
  inputStream$.pipe(
    take(1),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)),
  inputStream$.pipe(
    skip(1),
    debounceTime(500),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$))
).subscribe(val => someFunction(val));
```

**On the concat-stream itself:**

```
concat(
  inputStream$.pipe(take(1)),
  inputStream$.pipe(
    skip(1),
    debounceTime(500))
).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(val => someFunction(val));
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: The second one is the right one because if you unsubscribe from an observable created by `concat` it will automatically unsubscribe from its sources.

Comment: `concat(...).pipe(takeUntil())` is the right way to do it. Also have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783869/cancel-flatmap-observable-call-chain/54784198 and this article https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef even though the first option will work as well (it's just a little longer).

Comment: I see. Maybe it should be obvious too, since there would be nothing subscribing to the concat anyways with the 2nd solution.